# Taking a Windows screenshot with JNI

Tags: c, windows, java-native-interface

I'm trying to take a screenshot natively with JNI on Windows, but I just can't seem to do it. Partly because I don't fully understand how this works. I already have knowledge of JNI, but I can't get this screenshot thing to work. I got to the point where I have an HBITMAP and I call GetDIBits, but I don't understand why I need to call that and why doesn't it work. If someone could help me with this that'd be really appreciated!

```
HDC hScreenDC = CreateDC(L"DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);
HDC hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);

int width = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, HORZRES);
int height = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, VERTRES);

int size = height * (width * 3);

printf("Width: %d, height: %d, size: %d", width, height, size);

if (width <= 0 && height <= 0) {
    return NULL;
}

HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, width, height);
HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);

BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, width, height, hScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hOldBitmap);

BITMAPINFO bmi;
bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = 0;
bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = size;
bmi.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmi.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmi.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
bmi.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

char* scanlines = new char[size];

bool result = GetDIBits(hMemoryDC, hBitmap, 0, height, scanlines, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

if (!result) {
    printf("GetDIBits failed!");
    return NULL;
}

DeleteDC(hScreenDC);
DeleteDC(hMemoryDC);

jbyteArray returnArray = env->NewByteArray(size);
jbyte* jBytes = env->GetByteArrayElements(returnArray, FALSE);

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(scanlines); i++) {
    jBytes[i] = scanlines[i];
}

env->SetByteArrayRegion(returnArray, 0, size, jBytes);

return returnArray;
```

Comment: It's impossible to say why code doesn't work without code.

Comment: edited with the code

Comment: And at what point does it fail? And how?

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest apparent problem, just from looking at the code, is calling sizeof on a pointer, which will give you back 4 always on 32 bit, so you are actually only working with the first 4 lines.

More correct would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    jBytes[i] = scanlines[i];
}
```